# При попытке компиляции пишет: mutex is not a member of std

Tags: c++, mingw

```
#include<mutex>
#include<thread>

int main()
{
    std::mutex tMutex;
    return 0;
}
```

компилирую в `msys`

```
g++ -o 1 1.cpp -Wall -std=c++14 -lpthread
```

Comment: Попробуйте указывать имя файла после параметров сборки.

Comment: пробовал - не помогло

Comment: вы подключили pthread, а в нём есть mutex видимо, уберите pthread

Comment: там опечатка: это просто `thread`. И при чем тут есть `mutex` там или нет? Сдесь же указано `std::mutex`.

Comment: `g++ -v` что выдает?

Comment: версия компилятора 6.3.0

Comment: Меня интересует `thread model`, в конце вывода

Comment: оно имеет значение win32

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Вам нужен MinGW с posix-потоками, т.е. posix-seh или posix-dwarf

Comment: Для win32-потоков есть сторонняя реализация: https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads. Правда не знаю, как её чистенько прикрутить, на сколько она соответствует стандарту и почему её не приняли в mingw (не пытались пропихнуть?)...