# Ошибка в библиотеке functional? - C++

Tags: c++, qt

При попытке подключения библиотеки thread или mutex компиляция падает.
Ошибка находится в библиотеке functional из стандарта C++
При ее подключении программа падает.
Компилятор жалуется на этот код:

```
astatic_assert(_Varargs::value
                ? sizeof...(_BoundArgs) >= _Arity::value + 1
                : sizeof...(_BoundArgs) == _Arity::value + 1,
                "Wrong number of arguments for pointer-to-member");
};
```

Раньше все работало отлично. Компилятор - MinGW
[image]

Comment: Вопрос в том, какой код вы **компилируете**. Не просто же так валится - от одного `#include<thread>`?

Comment: В любом проекте, даже пустом.

Comment: Что-то это, мягко говоря, **очень** странно. Т.е. вот это - https://ideone.com/Gpiu9I - у вас не компилируется?

Comment: @Harry, нет, не компилируется: http://prntscr.com/jh0my2

Comment: Без thread все отлично: http://prntscr.com/jh0npx

Comment: Мда, что-то поломано, но что и где? никаких идей...

Comment: недавно обсуждали: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821000/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b5%d1%82-mutex-is-not-a-member-of-std

Comment: 4 дня назад все работало отлично. На следующий день начала валиться компиляция, и я занялся поиском проблемы. Когда нашел ошибку в библиотеке стандарта - написал сюда.

Comment: Сделай препросессинг этого примера https://prnt.sc/jh0my2, посмотри что компилятор получает на вход, возможно где-то не так макрос раскрывается или какой-то лишний include попадает

Comment: @ffk каким образом?

Comment: `каким образом` — в `.pro`-файле добавьте строку `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -E`. Затем удалите папку сборки (как правило она лежит рядом с папкой проекта и имеет в своём названии слово «build»), пересоберите проект, перейдите в эту папку (она пересоздаётся при сборке) и найдите в ней файл `main.o`. Откройте его в Блокноте — внутри будет ваш код со всем развёрнутыми директивами препроцессора. Его-то и надо выложить.

Comment: И ещё. Вы ничего не (пере)устанавливали/удаляли/обновляли перед тем, как перестало работать?

Comment: Нет, я ничего не трогал.
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -E вызывает ошибки:  
(main.o:-1: ошибка: file not recognized: File format not recognized)   и 
(collect2.exe:-1: ошибка: error: ld returned 1 exit status)

Comment: @Arhad, вот main.o с #include<thread>: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Q7yD2CIZvBIUSG5KIU2lFOJTiET8dT5w

Comment: А флаг для "включения поддержки" C++11 добавлен? 
```CONFIG += c++11```

Comment: @Croessmah, да.

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на стандарт Си++ который указан в параметрах компиляции. Потому что ругается компилятор на многоточие из строки `sizeof...(_BoundArgs)`. Такие конструкции с многоточиями появились только с версии Си++17 они служат для свертки параметров шаблонов. Так как ваш компилятор на знает о них, то видимо он поддерживает старые версии стандарта.

GCC имеет специальный ключ для указания версии стандарта `-std`, для Си++17 нужно указать `-std=c++17`.

Comment: CONFIG += c++17 
-std=c++17 
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17
Ничего из этого не работает. Компилятор - MinGW

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jqkpdb
Теперь, кстати, любое приложение не компилируется.

Answer (score 0):

возможно для компилятора не стандартная библиотека, попробуйте подключить через

```
#pragma comment( lib, "thread" )
```

или добавить в свойствах проекта.
Меняли обновляли версию компилятора?

Comment: Не менял, и не обновлял ничего.
Ваш способ не работает.
http://prntscr.com/jjjxah

Comment: Попробуйте #include <pthread.h>

Comment: А добавлять в проект пробовали?

Comment: #include <pthread.h> не работает. 
Каким образом можно добавить в проект библиотеку?

Comment: Да и смысла добавлять из компилятора minGW нет.
что-то в functional сломано.